# What are the spell correct api's available?

Tags: api, nlp, spell-checking, autocorrect

I wanted to know the spell correct api's available for commercial/non commercial usage other than google/bing.

Comment: Got this: http://www.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=test
But marks you as bot once you par the threshold. I guess.

Comment: You can use this: https://serpapi.com/spell-check

Comment: This one: https://tisane.ai supports multiple languages, and can also segment hashtags / etc.

Comment: @VadimBerman tisane.ai looks decent and contains much more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you can write your own spell corrector with [this](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) tutorial. In addition there are some Python packages that may help you with that, such as [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/) (which I highly recommend). Another option is [Gingerit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gingerit) which Iv'e never tried but looks promising. [Another](https://www.kaggle.com/hiendang/crowdflower-search-relevance/auto-correct-query) DIY spell correct tutorial might interest you as well.

Comment: Thanks Lior. Implementing my own spell corrector(ref: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Answer (score 2):

https://www.gigablast.com/spellcheckapi.html

I just launched this, so it's still beta, but it's not bad. It has a dictionary of over 600,000,000 entries covering most non-Asian languages.